# Element that can only have one of two text values?

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm constructing a DTD which has a `fuel_system` element.

I want to restrict the text between `<fuel_system>` tag. It must be only `carbureted` or `fuel-injected`. How can I do this?

I don't mention something like this = > attribute type (carbureted, fuel-injected), because I want to force this rule in `<fuel_system>` tags, not the attribute of `fuel_system`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

when defining an element in a DTD, there is no way to restrict the **text** inside the element. you can only tell what other element (child elements) it might contain and their order, or you can tell that the element contains text, or a mixture of the 2.

so, basically you have 2 options for restricting the `<fuel-system>`: either declare it as an attribute (`<fuel-system type="fuel-injected"/>`), or declare children elements `<fuel-injected>` and `<carburated>`. the choice between those 2 options depends on what you are trying to describe and what will change depending on the type of `fuel-system`.

(the grammar for the declaration of an element is defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-elementdecl))

**examples**: *first option*, attributes

```
<!ELEMENT fuel-system EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST fuel-system (fuel-injected|carburated) #REQUIRED>
```

*second option*, child elements

```
<!ELEMENT fuel-system (fuel-injected|carburated)>
<!ELEMENT fuel-injected ...>
<!ELEMENT carburated ...>
```

Comment: I convince to my teacher it is not possible in DTD and I will construct my DTD like your response..Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Does it **have** to be a DTD?  Is XML Schema an option?

[Using XML Schema you can restrict element text to an enumerated list of values](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp):

```
<xs:element name="fuel-system">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="fuel-injected"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="carbourated"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Your response is an another answer of my duty.Thanks a lot :)