# How can i restrict the text of an element?

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DTD element type problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778401/dtd-element-type-problem)

I have an xml in which i have element facilities.

Internet

Facilities can have at least one or more of the followings: Internet, Gym, Free Parking, Restaurant, Pick-up, Pool, Conference hall, Banquet hall.
How can i apply this in dtd and schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can certainly do that with the schema, that allows you to restrict values to an enumeration of set values. More information on [this Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778401/dtd-element-type-problem)