# Declaring enumeration on elements in DTD

Tags: enums, dtd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DTD element type problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778401/dtd-element-type-problem)

Is this possible to restrict values on a element with DTD ?

In this example, I want to restrict animal type to cat or dog only :

```
<example>
   <animal>
      <type>cat</type>
   </animal>
   <animal>
      <type>dog</type>
   </animal>
   <animal>
      <type>fish</type> <-- Error here
   </animal>
</example>
```

I know this is possible to restrict attributes but is this possible with elements please ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1778401/407651?

Comment: Yes indeed. Thank you for this link