# XML - Elements having multiple values

Tags: xml

I have an element that must contain only specific values in xml  but there may be more that one of that element.However the dtd seems to be wrong(skipping irrelevant parts)

dtd

```
<!ELEMENT Country ( US | UK | France | Italy ) >
```

xml

```
<table>
    <details>
        <Country>US</CINEMA>
        <Country>Italy</CINEMA>
        <Country>UK</CINEMA>
    </details>
```

Here is the error that i get when using [xmlvalidator](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)

```
The content of element type "Country" must match "( US | UK | France | Italy )"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DTD restricts content of `<Country>` elements to 4 possible child elements. So example of valid `<Country>` elements according to the DTD would be :

```
<Country>
    <US></US>
</Country>
<Country>
    <Italy></Italy>
</Country>
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to restrict text node content inside an element using DTD. Related question : [Element that can only have one of two text values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778401/element-that-can-only-have-one-of-two-text-values)

Comment: Can you please show me a valid dtd according to the xml instead?

Comment: `<!ELEMENT Country (#PCDATA) >`

Comment: I need to have only  `US | UK | France | Italy ` in `Country`

Comment: *"Unfortunately, there is no way to restrict text node content inside an element using DTD"*. See the linked question. There is a way using XML schema, if you can afford to switch from DTD